# slf4j is not managed through logback.xml

Tags: java, logging, slf4j

I need a little help, I'm developing a bot in my java telegram and I thought to insert slf4j as a loggin system, so you can manage the log through a server-side xml file, I wanted to print the log on the file, only since that moment it seems that the loggin system is not managed anymore by the xml file also because I only print the ERROR level logs even if I inject the debug level.
Another note that I think is relevant and that on the server I get a SEVERE type error and I do not type you ERROR so from here I have deduced that the logger is managed differently, how can I solve it?

I'll post my logback.xml file

```
<configuration>
  <timestamp key="byDay" datePattern="yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss"/>

  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
      <level>INFO</level>
      <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
      <onMismatch>DENY</onMismatch>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file> log-${byDay}.txt </file>
    <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%-4relative [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="debug">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: So, what I've gathered from your description is that you're not using Logback, so logback.xml isn't going to do anything. So, what logging system *are* you using? (SLF4J is just a facade over a "real" logging system, so saying you're using it doesn't help us understand what logging system you're trying to configure.)

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Yes, I think the log file is not connected to the loggin system that is using the telegram APIs, but the question that arises to me is why first the loggin system, ie logback was working before? and above all now how can I solve?

Comment: @PeterCooperJr. Fixed, Fixed, it was the first time I approached maven and I had the wrong amount libraries, I had imported those with which I used log4j,
so I trivially solved adding the right code in the pom.xml file replacing it with the one before